# Best Practices for back up the SharePoint 2013 3-Tier Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, backup, tape

Wanted to know what are the best practices for backing up the SharePoint farm and Sql Server DBs. 
I'm having 3 tier farm having 2 WFEs, 2 app servers and  1 sql server with clustering and mirroring enabled.
On what frequency I need to take the backup of Sql Server Content DBs, SharePoint's entire farm backup.

Is it mandatory that I need to take backup the content DBs on a Tape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really tough to agree on single point as backup & restore requirement vay customer to customer. But their are many options to choose from, you can pick one which is really suitable and fullfill all your requirement. There are 3 common method

1. SharePoint Backup
2. SQl backups
3. 3rd Party Tools ( MicroSoft System Center DPM)

All method having their prons and cons. You have to test which ever method you pick. Also Make sure it give you minimum recovery time.Following things you can test

- How quickly the farm/database/site can be restored
- how granular you can go with recovery
- How much space requirement and etc

[SharePoint 2010: Backup and Restore Best Practices](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/surama/2012/05/29/sharepoint-2010-backup-and-restore-best-practices/)

[Backup and restore best practices in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266384.aspx)

Comment: that was a helpful comment  and will go through this and update. BTW, am having about 100GB of data growth is expected in one year. And customer is planning to have  2/3  more web appls too going to be introduced in the SP FARM

Comment: it is not too much, one of my client having 12TB of data and he is relying on SQL backups(content, service) and windows server backup( which will backup all drives)